# How to run an sql query from a link with javascript onclick

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, joomla

I have a script in a joomla article that goes through the database and lists all entries by a use. Everything is done in PHP with echo statements in it.

At the end of each entry, I added a "delete" button.

For example:

```
    echo "[a href=\"#\" onclick=\"javascript:(NEED TO RUN QUERY HERE)\"]Delete[/a]";
```

How can I do this?

(please ignore the square brackets, I wasn't sure how to make the code show and the pre tag didnt work that well)

Comment: AJAX, using [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/using_XMLHttpRequest), and a serverside script which handles requests after *VALIDATING* the user's identity.

Comment: @Murtez: for code blocks, highlight the code and then hit ctrl-K or the `{}` button in the editor. If you want to embed a short snippet within a large block of non-code, use backticks around the code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax, you would make a call from javascript to your php script, return the data in JSON, parse it and  append the entries to the dom

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at this http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_intro.asp it should lead you through the steps you requested to setup AJAX.  The left side has links how you would code it in PHP and also make Database queries.

I recommend just taking the sample code and adjusting it to meet your needs.  Have fun!

Comment: If you are going to leave a comment like that please post your alternative method or where the example is wrong.  Otherwise your comment is nonconstructive when it comes to the problem above.

Comment: I'm not objecting to your solution (use ajax).  I *am* objecting to the link. I started out with the W3Schools too - but in the example for querying information from a MySQL database the W3Schools example leaks the `xmlhttp` variable into the global scope, does not encode the values being sent over the wire in the query string parameter, is in quirks mode because the HTML does not have *any* doctype **and** exposes the database to SQL Injection attacks by dropping the value of `$_GET["q"]` directly into the SQL query. That's all in one page, without *any* caveats from the author.

Answer (score 0):

here is an example on how you would do it using jquery ajax.

```
$('#buttonid').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "pathtoserversidescipt",
    data: $("#formid").serialize(),
    success: function(msg){
        ("whatever you want to happen next")
    }
});
});
```

Also check here to learn more. http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

Answer (score 0):

You need to post that link by ajax to edit section. In edit section you can get the post id and remove it like

```
if(isset($_GET['delete']) and $_GET['delete'] != '')
```

and remove

```
function remove() {
    $id = JRequest::getVar('id');
    $db =& JFactory::getDBO();
    $query = "DELETE FROM #__cd_lend_request WHERE ck_CDid = '$id'";
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $result = $db->query();
    $this->setRedirect(JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_cd'), 'CD has been removed from the list!', 'notice');
}
```